# event.cancel usage in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, internet-explorer-11

I have an old application that contains the following JavaScript code to handle a key-down event:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.cancel = true;
    document.getElementById(btnId).click();
    return false;
}

return true;
```

What it should do is to check if the user pressed the enter key, and if so simulate a click on a button and do not execute the default action of the key-down event.

This works fine in Google Chrome, Firefox and IE8. However, it does not work in IE11. How can I make this code work in IE11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that setting `event.cancel` to `false` does not do anything in IE11. The accepted way to cancel the default event handling is to use the `event.preventDefault()` function. The following code fixes the problem and works on IE11, Chrome and Firefox:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById(btnId).click();
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: what do you mean "further processing of the key-down event."? FOr further processing dont you mean event.stopPropogation()?

Comment: @Wishy I expressed myself incorrectly, what I want is to cancel the default event. The text has been updated.